# How to get a specific duration ( or less than that ) video paths using MediaStore

Tags: android, video, media-queries, mediastore

I'm able to get the paths of all videos in the filesystem using MediaStore. is there any way to get a specific duration (or less than that) video using MediaStore. like video duration less than 15min.

These are my code to get the video paths

```
public void getVideoPaths(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            filesNames.add(c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String duration = Integer.toString(15*60*1000);
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION + " < ?", new String[] {duration}, null);
```

This will query for only files shorter than 15 minutes

Comment: context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION + " < ?", new String[] {duration}, null);      DURATION we should add right

Answer (score 0):

The MediaStore is a Media provider that contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices. You just need to have a uri of that video file than use below code for duration purpose

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(uriOfYourFile));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
```

And after that check for specific  duration. You can use one more option as well as mentioned below

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
//use one of overloaded setDataSource() functions to set your data source
retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );

retriever.release()
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This method will create a MediaPlayer for each and every file right ?

Comment: so it will slow up my process